# Building `netty-tcnative` for Android 4.x

Tags: android, openssl, netty

I would like to use OpenSSL with Netty 4.1.17 on Android 4.x. The maven builds of `netty-tcnative` include only the x86_64 implementations. Is there documentation on how to build `netty-tcnative` for Android runtime environments?
I have the Android NDK installed, but I'm not sure how to configure the netty-tcnative build to use it. And presumably I need to build x86_32 as well as various ARM targets?

Comment: did you ever get this working?

Comment: No, I was not able to get this to work. We gave up.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly we never tried this and I am not sure it will work. That said it should be as easy as calling `mvn clean package` but again I am not sure if this will work. We also ship a dockerfile in the repository which will include all needed native dependencies etc.